# How to Tagged PDF with low level object of itextpdf-5.5.13

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I am trying to create tagged PDF using low level object of itext5 as below

```
    document.open();
    PdfStructureTreeRoot structureTreeRoot = writer.getStructureTreeRoot();
    PdfStructureElement top = new PdfStructureElement(structureTreeRoot, PdfName.DOCUMENT);
    PdfStructureElement element = new PdfStructureElement(top, PdfName.P);
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, false);
    cb.setLeading(16);
    cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
    cb.beginText();
    cb.setTextMatrix(50, 700);
    cb.beginMarkedContentSequence(element);
    cb.newlineShowText("Hello There");
    cb.endMarkedContentSequence();
    cb.endText();
    document.close();`
```

Code generates pdf which is open in acrobat DC pro but when I check tags,acrobat is not responding.
While checking structure tree in itext-rups I found StructureTreeRoot array contains null instead of StructureElement and also in XRef 2nd and 3rd objects are missing [image: Structure tree in itext-rups]

I am new to pdf generation and wrote code taking reference from [Tagged PDF](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0419__PDF/TaggedPDF.htm). It is mandatory to use itext5 low level object for project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using low level APIs here, there is quite a lot of work you explicitly have to do which otherwise is done automatically for you.

In the case at hand for example you have to explicitly add the `PdfStructureElement` to the document before closing it, i.e.

```java
[...]
cb.endText();
writer.addToBody(element, element.getReference());
writer.addToBody(top, top.getReference());
document.close();
```